# Addition using exponents

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

Is it possible to use exponents as a form of *addition*? For example in $5^{1.x} = 6$ where $x$ is the numbers after the decimal place. If so, what would be the equation to find $x$?

Comment: Not clear on your notation. What is the exponent?  If, say, $x=2$, what is the left hand of your expression?

Comment: Yes. If I get your notation right, you can take $\log$ from both sides and rewrite $1.x$ as $1+\frac{x}{10}$, which comes down from the exponent. Then solve linearly for $x$.

Comment: For your example, $x \approx 0.1133$.

Comment: Thanks all! Especially O. Von Seckendorff. Lulu: for clarification I meant (as an example) 5^1.1133

Comment: O. Von Seckendorff what do you mean log (I know this means logarithm) both sides? Wouldn't I need an exponent and base etc?

Comment: In this case log means log base 5.  i.e $5^{1+x} = 6$ means $1+x = \log_5 6$.  Now to figure out what $\log_5 6$ is if you don't have an input for that on your calculator.....  $log_n k = \log_b k/log_b n$ for all bases.  So $\log_5 6 = \log_{10} 6/\log_{10} 5 = \ln 6/\ln 5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you are asking how do you solve $b^{a + x} = k$ for $x$ if $b,a,k$ are constants; for example how would you solve $5^{1 + x} = 6$.  Is that right.

Like so:

$5^{1 + x} = 6$

$\log_5 5^{1+x}= \log_5 6$

$1 +x = \log_5 6$

$x = \log_5 6 - 1$

$x = \frac{\ln 6}{\ln 5} - 1$

$x = 1.113...-1=0.113...$

In general $b^{a + x} = k$

if $x = \log_b k - a$

====

To figure out what $\log_b k$ is ... $\log_b k = \frac{\log_x k}{\log_x b} = \frac{\log_{10} k}{\log_{10} b}= \frac{\log_e k}{\log_e b}= \frac{\ln k}{\ln b}$

Comment: how did you get from x = log5 6 - 1 to x = in... and why are we using in?

Comment: $\ln$ = "natural log" =$ \log_e$; e = 2.717.......  $\log_b k = \log_x k/\log_x b$ for any x whatsoever. $ \log_5 6 = \log_{10} 6/\log_{10} 5 = \log_e 6/\log_e 5 = \log_{29.753} 6/\log_{29.7653} 5$.  Chances are you do not have a $\log_5$ button on your calculator.  Doesn't matter as you probably have a $\ln$ button.  And you can always solve $\log_b k = \frac{\ln k}{\ln b}$ you can also solve $\log_b k = \frac{\log_{10} k}{\log_{10} b}$.  But $\log_{10} $ is what *physicists* use.  Real *mathematicians* use $\ln = \log_e$.  :)

Comment: If $b^k = N$ then $\log_b N =k$.  That's a definition.  By definition $x^{\log_x b} = b$.   So if $b^k = N$ then $x^{k*\log_x b} = N$ so $\log_x x^{k\log_x b} = \log_x N$ so $k \log_x b = \log_x N$ so $k = \frac{\log_x N}{\log_x b}$ so $k = \log_b N =\frac{\log_x N}{\log_x b}$.  So $\log_5 6 = \frac{\log_{10}5}{\log_{10}6}=\frac{\ln 5}{\ln 6}$.

Comment: Thanks! I think my brain just broke though... Also, why do we use e? And I know it is 2.718281828459.

Comment: And I thought (Phi^n - phi^n)/sqrt5 was complicated.... Can someone tell me how to use division bars and superscript please?

Comment: Fleablood you are a genius btw

Comment: It doesn't matter what base you use.  For any base, $b > 0; b\ne 0$ with  $b^n=K$ and any other base $c > 0; c \ne 0$ we can convert from one to the other with $b^n= c^{n*\log_c b} $.  Because any base is just as good as any other, scientists, particularly those who deal with large numbers such as the number of molecules in a liter of gas or the speed of light in meters per second, like to use $\log_10$ so the can do practical metric and base 10 conversions....

Comment: .... mathematicians don't care about actual values and quantities and we *know* 10 is utterly arbitrary?  (Why 10?  Why not 13? Or 7? Or 12? Or 26?)  Arbitrary *galls* us. So we prefer base $e=2.717.... $.  What's so special about $e $.  Well... calculus.  $b^n$ all have the same basic shape in wish they grow very fast based on what current value it is now.  How *fast* $b^n $ grows is actually equal to $c_b*b^n $ where $c_b$ is some constant depending on $n$.  $e$ is the number where $c_e=1$ exactly.  And for *all* other $b $, $c_b=\log_e b $.

Comment: Thanks! How did you figure all this out? The equation I mean.

Comment: It's well known and a standard property of logarithms.  Basically for every rule of exponents $b^nb^m = b^{n+m}; (b^n)^m = b^{nm}$ must have equivalent rules for logartithms $\log a*b = \log a + \log b; \log b^n = n*\log b$ And as if $b^k = c;$ and $c^n =d $ we have $(b^k)n =d$ so $\log_c d =n$ and $\log_b d = kn$ and $n = \log_c d = \log_b d/\log_b c$ etc.  You learn these after a while.

Comment: Wow... So basically the answer for my question (the original one) is b^(In(b+1)/In(b))

Comment: Hey, I am now almost done with Algebra 2 and I completely understand this. It makes a lot of sense! I think what you basically did was 5^\log_5 6, which simplifies down to x being In6/In5 because of change base theorem